# Вопрос: "Как сама?"

Tags: словосочетания, смысл

Человек тебе пишет:" Как сама ?". По смыслу можно понять, что он хочет узнать как у тебя дела или спросить "как ты?". Но думаю, что этот вопрос можно задать только  в следующей ситуации: например , один спрашивает "как ты?" Другой: "я норм. Как ты сам или как сам то?" Так ли я полагаю, что изначально начинать беседу с такого вопроса неправильно? Получается  коверкается значение и употребление слова "сама"?

**Какова синтаксическая роль, смысл и контекст этого местоимения  в данном вопросе?**

Answer (score 1):

Сам - так полушутя говорили раньше о большом начальнике, например: "Как Сам себя сегодня чувствует?". (Тогда было принято говорить с придыханием: "Сегодня я видел **самого** товарища имярек!".) В вопросе "Как сама?" я вижу отголосок того юмора. Может, я и не прав, но, в любом случае, это обращение несерьезное, и относиться к нему нужно с юмором, примерно так же, как если бы кто-то начинал диалог с фразы "И у меня все хорошо".

Comment: Согласна, что воспринимать такой вопрос можно , как "сленговое" выражение. Но все -таки, какова синтаксическая роль, смысл и контекст местоимения "сама" в данном вопросе?

Comment: Анастасия, если Вы так досконально подходите к теме, то включите это в состав основного вопроса — пусть учителя грамотно ответят.